# Use of Undefined Constant Notice on CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, constants

I checked whole site but couldn't find any answers about it, so I decided to post a question.

I'm developing a website with CodeIgniter 3.0 and oftenly getting this notice below:

```
Severity: Notice

Message: Use of undefined constant   - assumed ' '

Filename: yonetim/master.php

Line Number: 149

Backtrace:

File: /home/address/public_html/application/views/yonetim/master.php
Line: 149
Function: _error_handler

File: /home/address/public_html/application/controllers/yonetim/Anasayfa.php
Line: 9
Function: view

File: /home/address/public_html/index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once
```

Line 149 on master.php is below:

```
<li <?php if($this->uri->segment(3) == 'bayiler') { ?>class="active"<?php } ?>>
```

I know, I can disable notification alert on index.php but I don't want to make it with this way. Do you know right solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: make sure you have placed spaces correctly

Comment: Great. You may upvote my comment if it helps. Thanks